# What's the UFC rules regarding steroid usage?

Tags: rules, doping, mma

Per [this article](http://www.msn.com/en-us/sports/mma/mcgregor-not-on-steroids-%E2%80%A6-just-an-animal/ar-BBpX4Tc) <sub>(1)</sub> and after watching [this press conference video](http://www.bloodyelbow.com/2016/2/24/11108632/ufc-196-conor-mcgregor-vs-nate-diaz-press-conference-video) <sub>(2)</sub> it's so hilarious all the trash that McGregor is talking; funny stuff, but this brings up my question.

What's the UFC rules regarding steroid usage, and when do fighters get tested? Can the public access these records and what are the consequences of someone testing positive?

---

### References

- [McGregor: 'Not on steroids … just an animal'](http://www.msn.com/en-us/sports/mma/mcgregor-not-on-steroids-%E2%80%A6-just-an-animal/ar-BBpX4Tc)(1)
- [UFC 196: McGregor vs. Diaz press conference video](http://www.bloodyelbow.com/2016/2/24/11108632/ufc-196-conor-mcgregor-vs-nate-diaz-press-conference-video)(2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The U.S. Anti-Doping Agency (USADA) administers the UFC's drug testing policy.  They have a website at [ufc.usada.org](http://ufc.usada.org/), and on this website you can read the [21-page policy (pdf)](http://ufc.usada.org/wp-content/uploads/UFC-anti-doping-policy-EN.pdf), which took effect on July 1, 2015.

Every UFC fighter is subject to unannounced, year-round drug testing by the USADA.  The sanctions for testing positive is dependent on the substance found.  For performance-enhancing drugs such as steroids, growth hormones, blood doping, etc., the ban is 2 years for the first offense.  For other drugs, such as marijuana or cocaine, the ban is 1 year for the first offense.  For subsequent offenses, the length of the ban doubles.  Two years can be added to the ban for "aggravating circumstances," which are defined in the policy.

You can see which athletes have been tested and how many times on the [Athlete Test History](http://ufc.usada.org/testing/results/athlete-test-history/) page of the website.  So far this year, 240 athletes have been tested 335 times.

Answer (score -2):

I am going to keep my answer very short and just link here:
http://www.mmafighting.com/2015/6/3/8724535/revamped-ufc-drug-policy-includes-random-year-round-testing-two-year

EDIT:

In summary this is what it says:
Random testing,
Up to 2 years ban.